# Can't change "Region/Coutry" in Payment Information for Azure Account Registration

Tags: azure, outlook, hotmail

I want to register for an azure account (my free account is already older than 12 months). In the Page for "Payment Information" I cannot change "Region/Coutry". It's fixed to Germany, but I don't live there anymore and my credit card has a different adress (not in germany).

How do I change that?

The Region on my laptop is correct (not germany).
I already tried to change the Location in my hotmail-account as well, but this didn't fix the problem, I am still not able to change the Country in the "Payment Information".

Did anybody encounter the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Update your country or region
Changing the country or region for an existing account isn't supported. However, you can create a new account in a different country or region and then contact Azure support to transfer your subscription to the new account.
For more information refer to this article: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/change-azure-account-profile#:~:text=Update%20your%20country%20or%20region,subscription%20to%20the%20new%20account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/change-azure-account-profile#:%7E:text=Update%20your%20country%20or%20region,subscription%20to%20the%20new%20account).

If you still find any difficulties, the Billing and Subscription team would be the best to provide more insight and guidance on this scenario:   **Free** [billing and subscription management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/) support have been provided.